# JCE cannot authenticate the provider BC in Webapp deployed in Jboss. Why?

Tags: java, security, cryptography, keystore

I'm new to crypto stuff in java. I'm trying to get key info. from .p12 file using keystore.load(stream, char[]) method of java 1.7. I'm using this in my web app deployed in Jboss eap 6.

It is throwing below error from my app.

```
java.io.IOException: error constructing MAC: java.lang.SecurityException: JCE cannot authenticate the provider BC
```

I tried to replicate the same using some simple dynamic web project. It works fine when it is deployed alone in Jboss. If i add my real app along with this sample app, and if i run my **sample app** it is throwing the above error.

Simply put, if my sample app is alone, it is fine, if it got company it gives error.

I couldnt get any info while debug too. Some light on this error will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

i followed as like in below link, my problem got solved.

Jboss eap 6 should know about the bouncycastle jar, so i have added that jar and module.xml in the JBOSS_HOME/modules. Then it is working good.

http://w3facility.org/question/bouncycastle-jboss-as7-jce-cannot-authenticate-the-provider-bc/

Comment: Hi Manoj, thanks for reporting back. Answers should contain a short description however, not just a link.

Comment: Link is not available anymore :-(